# How to update MPNowPlayingInfoCenter/MPRemoteCommandCenter play/pause controls with AVAudioPlayerNode?

Tags: swift, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I am making a simple music player app that just plays audio using AVAudioEngine. When I pause the AVAudioPlayerNode, it does not update the play/pause control of the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter/MPRemoteCommandCenter. How do I update it?

I dont want to pause the entire AVAudioEngine and then resume to update the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter/MPRemoteCommandCenter play/pause control since it lags up my UI and there's a delay when playing back audio.

Does anyone have any idea or solution regarding this topic? The documentation is absolutely atrocious and no one knows a goddamn thing about AVAudioEngine. Anyone?

```
func pause() {
        playerNode.pause()
        audioEngine.pause() 
        
        displayLink?.isPaused = true
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.musicPlayerControlsManager.isPlaying = false
        }
    }
    
    
    func playPlayerNode() {
        if !audioEngine.attachedNodes.isEmpty && audioFile != nil {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.musicPlayerControlsManager.isPlaying = true
                self.displayLink?.isPaused = false
            }
            
            do {
                try audioEngine.start()
                playerNode.play()
                
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really do seem to need to stop all audio to influence the now playing lockscreen widget, so in your case that does in fact mean calling `pause()` on your `AVAudioEngine`. Maybe you can mitigate the restart lag by preloading/buffering.